# Drawing straight horizontal line on TradingView chart widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, tradingview-api

## Hi there

I have added TradingView Advanced Real-Time Chart Widget to my React crypto project. I have a problem with drawing lines on chart, from backend I get array of prices and I have to draw lines on chart at that level. I saw TradingView lightweight charts lib, but it hasn't got all the futures I need (drawing, writing and so on).

For example from backend I got price 29000, and I have to draw line at level 29000 using code, not widget tools.

[View of line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbo3X.png)

Chart component code:

```
/* eslint-disable new-cap */
/* eslint-disable no-return-assign */
/* eslint-disable no-new */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define */
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import s from "./Chart.module.scss"

let tvScriptLoadingPromise

export default function Chart() {
  const onLoadScriptRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    onLoadScriptRef.current = createWidget

    if (!tvScriptLoadingPromise) {
      tvScriptLoadingPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        const script = document.createElement("script")
        script.id = "tradingview-widget-loading-script"
        script.src = "https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"
        script.type = "text/javascript"
        script.onload = resolve

        document.head.appendChild(script)
      })
    }

    tvScriptLoadingPromise.then(
      () => onLoadScriptRef.current && onLoadScriptRef.current()
    )

    return () => (onLoadScriptRef.current = null)

    function createWidget() {
      if (
        document.getElementById("tradingview_81848") &&
        "TradingView" in window
      ) {
        const widget = new window.TradingView.widget({
          width: 1000,
          height: 680,
          symbol: "BINANCE:BTCUSDT",
          interval: "D",
          timezone: "Etc/UTC",
          theme: "dark",
          style: "1",
          locale: "en",
          toolbar_bg: "#f1f3f6",
          enable_publishing: false,
          hide_side_toolbar: false,
          allow_symbol_change: true,
          container_id: "tradingview_81848",
        })
      }
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="tradingview-widget-container">
      <div id="tradingview_81848" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I didn't find any api or docs for widget so I will be thankful for any help. Also, if you know any libs for charts like this [Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqKej.png) and easily customizable, feel free to share the link. Thx for your attention and help.